# Backup of Artifactory Instance - User not imported

Tags: artifactory, jfrog-cli, jfrog-mission-control

Will appreciate if someone can please throw some light on best way to backup and restore Artifactory. Primary concern being  the repository plus user and permission are available on restore.

I am trying System Export and import feature as well as incremental backup plus import but having no success with user/permissions when restore happens. Expecting to see ALL users after import from source - but net results are opposite -  after restore completes only user I see is access-admin. 
I even lose the user and anonymous on destination instance.

As per Arti. doc  https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Importing+and+Exporting  ,system export and import should take care of ething including security BUT my tests does not seem to have user info on import. 
From Doc. ***At system level, Artifactory can export and import the whole Artifactory server: configuration, security information, stored data and metadata. This is useful when manually running backups and for migrating and restoring a complete Artif. instance (as an alternative to using database level backup and restore).***

```
artifactory.version=5.9.3
artifactory.timestamp=1521564024289
artifactory.revision=50903900
artifactory.buildNumber=820
```

Default embedded derby mode . In new instance not restoring the db as  per my understanding documentation says - System Backup and Restore (ALL) will take care of all configurations.
  **But I am new to artifactory - Please correct me if my understanding is not correct.**

*Do like to point out restore is tried at seperately new spun  instance with jfrog ami and not on the instance from where data was backed*. 
This is to test if we lose our instance completely , can we spin the new aws instance and quickly restore the artifactory envoirnment back.
Thanks in advance for help.

Comment: Are you connecting new instance to the same database? Artifactory stores users in the database.

Comment: Thank you very much for your comment. I am just importing  - As per Arti. doc  https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Importing+and+Exporting  ,system export and import should take care of ething including security BUT my tests does not seem to have user info on import. From Doc. At system level, Artifactory can export and import the whole Artifactory server: configuration, security information, stored data and metadata. This is useful when manually running backups and for migrating and restoring a complete Artif. instance (as an alternative to using database level backup and restore).